# After installing iterm2 in the terminal, there was an error comment at the end

Tags: terminal, iterm2

After installation, it was confirmed that iterm2 was running normally.
Can you tell me what the last ERROR comment means?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F28HV.png)

I installed iterm2 in the terminal and I want you to know the last ERROR comment